# How to transfer skills from Rails tutorial to real project with real URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, web

I have been teaching myself Rails for some time with various tutorials and have been asked by a relative to create a basic personal website (static pages only) for them.  The relative already owns the domain at which they want the website to be created.

My question has to do with deploying an app that I create to a real domain.  In my tutorials I've learned about developing the app on my local machine, using Git for version control, and deploying to Heroku (eg http://name.herokuapp.com).  If someone wants me to develop the site that will live at www.website.com, how do I get my app  there?  Is there a good tutorial for this that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no rails expert, but a good place to start might be looking at the support docs for whatever host your client is using. Dreamhost has a [wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Ruby_on_Rails) covering RoR, and other hosts like [Hostgator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails) do as well.